# RDLC Report Update in Runtime

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, report, rdlc

I want to update rdlc report in runtime by reading xml in vb.net.
my report is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report ....
<DataSources>
....
</DataSources>
<DataSets>
<DataSet Name="DS_MAIN">
<Fields>
<Field Name="Value3">
      <DataField>Value3</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
</Field>
```

and im using to access this node like this

```
Dim MyXMLNode As Xml.XmlNode = MyXML.SelectSingleNode("/Report/DataSet[@Name='DS_MAIN']/Fields/Field[@Name='Value3']/DataField")
```

but my MyXMLNode wont get any value.
please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try XML Linq

```css
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()


        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim root As XElement = doc.FirstNode
        Dim ns = root.Name.Namespace
        Dim fields = doc.Descendants(ns + "Field").Select(Function(x) New With { _
            .name = x.Attribute("Name").Value, _
            .datafield = x.Element(ns + "DataField").Value, _
            .typeName = x.Descendants().Where(Function(y) y.Name.LocalName = "TypeName").Select(Function(z) z.Value).FirstOrDefault() _
       }).ToList()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, this is working fine with string but when i load whole report it wont output this is my report

Comment: this is the file i tried with this still wont give any output http://www.filedropper.com/2detailmainreport